# Change the task of a button placed in the footer of modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I have a modal. In the header of the modal I have title which is login. And in the body I have a login form and in the footer I have login button.

After the login button I have a hyper text for those who wants to create account which by clicking on it the login form disappear and the register form appears.

Is there any possibility that I can use the same button for logging in to register. (In the simplest word is it possible to use the same button in 2 different forms or if I can't, how can I add a button to the footer and make it act as the submit button of the reiteration form)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
  <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #222">
              <div class="mu-title">
              <span class="mu-subtitle" id = "loginTitle">Login</span>
        </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Body of the modal --> 
  <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: #222">

                      <form id="registerForm" method="POST" action="register.php" novalidate="novalidate" style="display: none">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="name" class="control-label" style="color: white">Full Name</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullName" name="fullName" value="" required="" title="Please enter you full name" placeholder="Full Name">
                              <span class="help-block"></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="username" class="control-label" style="color: white">Username</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="" required="" title="Please enter you username" placeholder="username@siswa.um.edu.my">
                              <span class="help-block"></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="password" class="control-label" style="color: white">Password</label>
                              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" value="" required="" title="Please enter your password">

                          </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="matrix" class="control-label" style="color: white">Matrix Number</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="matrixNO" name="matrixNO" value="" required="" title="Please enter you Matrix Number" placeholder="Matrix Number ">
                              <span class="help-block"></span>
                          </div>
                      </form>

                      <form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="login.php" novalidate="novalidate">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="username" class="control-label" style="color: white">Username</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="" required="" title="Please enter you username" placeholder="username@siswa.um.edu.my">
                              <span class="help-block"></span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="password" class="control-label" style="color: white">Password</label>
                              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" value="" required="" title="Please enter your password">

                          </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color: #222">
          <button type="submit"  id ="loginButt" class="mu-readmore-btn">Login</button></br></br>
          </form>
          <span style="color: white" >Create an <a href= "#" style="color: white" onClick="$('#loginForm').hide();$('#registerForm').show();  " >Account</a> </span>

  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you can do...simply ensure that you post the right form to right url

Comment: @RohitS The thing is my first form starts and finish before the starting of the second form (in the body of my modal) and then I start my second form in the body but close the tag in the footer of the model so the login button only works for login in and not registration

Comment: you have to do it with script..basically maintain an hidden filed that will keep the track of currently active form and read that value at submit click..depending upon outcome submit the form to appropriate url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some boilerplates that you can try with....(your part is just basically determining which form is active...)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submitbtn').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var form=$('#currentForm').val();
    if(form=="login")
      {
        alert('submit to login');
      }
    else
      {
        alert('submit to register');
      }
  });
  $('#btnchange').click(function(){
    var form=$('#currentForm').val();
    if(form=="login")
      {
        $('#currentForm').val('register');
        $('#registration-form').show();
        $('#login-form').hide();
      }
    else
      {
        $('#currentForm').val('login');
        $('#registration-form').hide();
        $('#login-form').show();
      }
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="register.php" name="registration-form" id="registration-form" style="display:none;">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="usename"><br/>
  <label for="emailid">Email ID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="emailid"><br/>
  <label for="password">Password :</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
</form><br/><br/>
<form method="post" action="login.php" name="login-form" id="login-form">
  <label for="emailid">Email ID :</label>
    <input type="text" name="emailid">
  <label for="password">Password :</label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
</form>
<input type="hidden" value="login" id="currentForm"/>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submitbtn" id="submitbtn">
<input type="button" value="Toggle Form" id="btnchange"/>
```

Comment: Thanks . This is what exactly I want :)

Comment: @DanialKosarifa glad to know that helped...:D

Answer (score 0):

Just so I understand your question a little bit better, the basic idea of what you're trying to do is:

Single page modal, one form. Take user text input, check for existing user with that info, create new user if none exists?